# Flutter: My checkbox does not announce change when clicked

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

I have only one checkbox ti remember user information when logged in! I used radiobutton at first but it didn't work so i changed to checkbox and the same happens.

This is how I declared my checkbox into my build method.

```
final remember=Checkbox(activeColor: Colors.green,
    value: statut,
    onChanged: (bool val) {setState(() {
      statut=val;
    });},);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it didn't work" do you have any error or console logs?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen and what actually happened?

Comment: Hey there, where are you declaring that Checkbox? Can you show how are you using it in the build method of your widget?

Comment: when I click to tick my checkbox it didn't show any change or any interaction! I'm declaring that in the widget build of course! no bugs and no logs ! just an interaction problem

Comment: what I mean is that the initial value I gave to the checkbox is what remains !! if false it's false if true it's true! the on changed doesn't seem to work correctly

Comment: can you share the full code ?